# API call fails with 401

Tags: javascript, api

I am using javascript and the axios library to make a get request to the Halo Developers' API ([www.haloapi.com](http://www.haloapi.com)). My code looks like this:

```
async function get() {
    let getData = async () => {
        let url = "https://www.haloapi.com/stats/h5/companies/111-222-333-444?key=[my key]";
        var response = await axios.get(url);
        return response.data;
    }
    let reply = await getData();
    return reply
}
```

(Simplified for your viewing) Executing this code yields a 401 api-key missing exception. However, a similar method of mine, identical except for the url works just fine. It reads like:

```
async function get() {
    let getData = async () => {
        let url = "https://www.haloapi.com/profile/h5/profiles/myplayername/appearance?key=[my key]";
        var response = await axios.get(url);
        return response.data;
    }
    let reply = await getData();
    return reply
}
```

Why would this happen? Does it have something to do with the dashes? I am really at a loss here.

Comment: the key is not set as a query param but instead in a header called `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`.. RTM: https://developer.haloapi.com/docs/services/58acdc2e21091812784ce8c2/operations/Halo-5-Player-Appearance

Comment: How come it works in the second method if that is an incorrect way to do it? Any idea how to do it that way with axios? I tried doing it the way they suggest in the documentation, and I couldn't get it to work for either link.

Comment: I should also mention, this is part of a larger vanilla js discord bot. I would rather not use ajax.

Comment: im not sure and would need to test.. to send a header  `axios.get('...', {
  headers: {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: '[my key]'
  }
})`

Comment: I've tried multiple variations of this... none of them work. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Just some '' off from being correct. If you want to post a more filled out solution I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the correct code looks like:

```
axios.get(url, { 'headers': { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key } });
```